# removing few lines from the given data using regex

Tags: python, regex

removing few lines from the given data using regex with particular pattern.

data:

```
'''And what struck me was every place that I went to to see these telescopes, the astronomers and cosmologists are in search of a certain kind of silence, whether it's silence from radio pollution or light pollution or whatever.
And it was very obvious that, if we destroy these silent places on Earth, we will be stuck on a planet without the ability to look outwards, because we will not be able to understand the signals that come from outer space.
Thank you.
<talkid>1129</talkid>
<title>Anil Ananthaswamy: What it takes to do extreme astrophysics</title>
<description>All over the planet, giant telescopes and detectors are looking for clues to the workings of the universe. At the INK Conference, science writer Anil Ananthaswamy tours us around these amazing installations, taking us to some of the most remote and silent places on Earth.</description>
<keywords>exploration,journalism,science,technology,universe</keywords>
<url>http://www.ted.com/talks/brewster_kahle_builds_a_free_digital_library.html</url>
We really need to put the best we have to offer within reach of our children.
If we don't do that, we're going to get the generation we deserve.
They're going to learn from whatever it is they have around them.'''
```

Here i want to remove the lines starting from `<talkid>`  to `</url>`

How can I use regex here ?

Tried:

```
re.sub('<.*?>', '', data)
```

Comment: You don't need to use regex.  `data_clean = '\n'.join(x for x in data.split('\n') if not x.startswith('<'))`

Comment: Thank you @James. It worked

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the regular expression `'<.*?>'` is that the `.` special character does not match newline characters by default. Compile your regular expression with the `re.DOTALL` flag to change this default behavior and match the string across multiple lines.

```
pattern = re.compile('<talkid>.*</url>', re.DOTALL)
new_text = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use regex, but if so - this will do the job:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'<talkid>.*</url>\n', re.DOTALL)
print(rgx.sub('', data))
```